# Oracle XE 11g How to create tables and insert data in one query?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am currently learning PL/SQL on Oracle Express Edition 11g and I want to create the 3 tables below in a single SQL query and insert the data. I can't find the solution to do it in a single query.

I tried several techniques but it never worked.

Can you explain or show me how to do it?

Thank you in advance for your help

```
CREATE TABLE  "COMPAGNIE" 
   (    "COMP" VARCHAR2(4), 
    "NOM_COMP" VARCHAR2(30), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_COMPAGNIE" PRIMARY KEY ("COMP") ENABLE
   )


CREATE TABLE avion
    (immat VARCHAR(6), typav VARCHAR(5),
    capacite NUMBER, comp VARCHAR(4),
    CONSTRAINT pk_avion PRIMARY KEY(immat),
    CONSTRAINT fk_comp FOREIGN KEY(comp)
        REFERENCES compagnie(comp)
    );


CREATE TABLE vols
    (numvol CHAR(6), date_vol DATE, immat VARCHAR(6), nb_p NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT pk_vols PRIMARY KEY (numvol, date_vol),
    CONSTRAINT fk_vols_immat FOREIGN KEY(immat)
        REFERENCES avion(immat)
    );


INSERT INTO compagnie VALUES ('AF', 'Air France');
INSERT INTO compagnie VALUES ('AC', 'Air China');
INSERT INTO compagnie VALUES ('AL', 'Air Liberté');
INSERT INTO compagnie VALUES ('AOM', 'Air Outre-Mer');
INSERT INTO avion VALUES('A1','A320',170, 'AF');
INSERT INTO avion VALUES('A2','B727',140, 'AC');
INSERT INTO avion VALUES('A3','B747',400, 'AF');
INSERT INTO avion VALUES('A4','A380',540, 'AF');
INSERT INTO vols VALUES('AF6143',to_date('10-01-2010','DD-MM-YYYY'),'A1',120);
INSERT INTO vols VALUES('AF6143',to_date('11-01-2010','DD-MM-YYYY'),'A1',130);
INSERT INTO vols VALUES('AF6143',to_date('13-01-2010','DD-MM-YYYY'),'A1',105);
INSERT INTO vols VALUES('AF6146',to_date('13-01-2010','DD-MM-YYYY'),'A4',530);
INSERT INTO vols VALUES('AF6146',to_date('14-01-2010','DD-MM-YYYY'),'A4',500);
INSERT INTO vols VALUES('AF6146',to_date('15-01-2010','DD-MM-YYYY'),'A4',534);
INSERT INTO vols VALUES('AF6146',to_date('16-01-2010','DD-MM-YYYY'),'A4',503);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this all in a single statement?  That would be very, very odd and generally much harder to manage.

Comment: I would like to do this in order to understand how to create several tables at once and how to create several inserts at once.

Comment: You can create several tables in a single SQL statement by putting them all in a `create schema` statement.  I have spent a couple of decades working with Oracle at a number of different companies and have not once encountered a situation where anyone has used a `create schema`.  I'd wager that the vast majority of Oracle developers have no idea that such a statement exists which would create issues for things like code reviews/ script generation/ etc.  Plus it makes life much harder when you have errors in one of your scripts that need to be debugged.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your feedback this is very enriching. :)

Comment: You can insert multiple rows into multiple tables in a single statement with an `insert all` statement.  That is likely to be more complicated than the statements you have and involve a bit more typing.  It also generally makes debugging a bit harder.  You can insert multiple rows in a single table using an `insert ... select` but that's going to be more cumbersome than what you have.  You can create a table and populate it with data in a single `create table as select` statement but you'd have to define your constraints separately.

Comment: Those `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` columns should really use the standard type for short strings, `VARCHAR2`. Also double-quoted names are generally not a good idea.